# C# type conversion, how to avoid the error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

A co-worker has an object that has a bunch of generic list collections on it. Each type in the list implements a given interface. He wants to be able to create a list that contains all the other lists so he can loop through and call the method the objects implement. Below is a simple example.

```
 List<Dx> dxs = new List<Dx>();
 dxs.Add(new Dx());
 dxs.Add(new Dx());

 List<Proc> procs = new List<Proc>();
 procs.Add(new Proc());

 List<List<IClean>> lists = new List<List<IClean>>();
 lists.Add(procs); // Error here
 lists.Add(dxs); // Error here

 foreach (List<IClean> list in lists)
 {
     foreach (IClean i in list)
     {        
         i.Clean();
     }
 }
```

Dx and Proc both implement IClean. This is the goal. Is something like this possible? Or, is this bad programming?

.NET Version 4.0

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: You can already answer the question "Is it possible?" by running the above code.

Comment: @RQDQ - The OP is getting an error with the above and is asking for options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just have a single `List<IClean>` that hold both implementations of `IClean`.

```
var list = new List<IClean>();
    list.Add(new Dx());
    list.Add(new Proc());

foreach(var clean in list)
{
   clean.Clean();
}
```

Furthermore, if you actually need to maintain two separate implementation lists and then process them together, you could do something like this:

```
var dx = new List<Dx>();
var proc = new List<Proc>();

List<IClean> list = new List<IClean>();
list.AddRange(dx);
list.AddRange(proc);

foreach(var clean in list)
{
   clean.Clean();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this using a `List` or an `IList`, because these types are not covariant. In other words, if you had a `List<IClean>`, you should be able to add a `Dx` to it, but if you had a `List<Proc>` you shouldn't. Therefore, a `List<Proc>` is not a `List<IClean>`.

Starting in .NET 4, you can do this with `IEnumerable<>`, though:

```
 List<Dx> dxs = new List<Dx>();
 dxs.Add(new Dx());
 dxs.Add(new Dx());

 List<Proc> procs = new List<Proc>();
 procs.Add(new Proc());

 List<IEnumerable<IClean>> lists = new List<IEnumerable<IClean>>();
 lists.Add(procs); 
 lists.Add(dxs); 

 foreach (List<IClean> list in lists)
 {
     foreach (IClean i in list)
     {        
         i.Clean();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach( var clean in procs.Cast<IClean>().Concat(dxs.Cast<IClean>()) )
{
    clean.Clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is LinqPad code snippet that will will output the following:

> Proc cleaned 
>   Dx cleaned 
>   Dx cleaned

```
void Main()
{
    List<IClean> dxs = new List<IClean>();  
    dxs.Add(new Dx());  
    dxs.Add(new Dx());   

    List<IClean> procs = new List<IClean>();  
    procs.Add(new Proc());   

    List< List<IClean> > lists = new List< List<IClean> >();  

    lists.Add(procs); 
    lists.Add(dxs);

    foreach (List<IClean> list in lists)
    {      
        foreach (IClean i in list)      
        {                  
            i.Clean();      
        }  
    } 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IClean 
{
  void Clean();
}
public class Dx : IClean
{
    public  void Clean()
    {
        "Dx cleaned".Dump();
    }
}

public class Proc : IClean
{
    public void Clean()
    {
        "Proc cleaned".Dump();
    }
}
```